# Is it right to say: Now he and Adam are being in the plane to the Great Barrier Reef and why?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentece right: Now he and Adam **are being** in the plane to the Great Barrier Reef? And please give an explanaison.

Comment: No, it is not correct. I have no idea why, I just speak the language I do not know the rules. Perhaps you can edit to explain why you think _being_ is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The words *am, is* and *are* are what we call *to-be* verbs.  Their usage already implies someone is *being* something.

*Bob is happy*, means Bob is *being* happy.  *He and Adam are on the plane*, means that he and Adam are *being* on the plane.

We only using *being* and a *to-be* verb together when *being* means *behaving in a certain way.* In your example *being* means *existing*.  Its usage is redundant and it should not be included.

There are some instances where the word being is necessary to express your idea.  *He and Adam, being on the plane, could only look out the window and whish they could help the crew on the tarmac.*

Comment: We do use "being" and be-verbs together though: "*My boss **is being** difficult*".

Comment: @gotube: yes we do, but only when _being_ means something like _behaving in a certain way_.

Answer (score 1):

No, "are being" is incorrect in your sentence.

The structure "am/is/are being" is *present continuous*. We only use present continuous for *action verbs*, never for *state verbs*. "Be" is almost always a state verb, as it is in your example, where it only describes the location of "he" and Adam.

To use "being" as an action verb, the subject must be doing some action. For instance, "being" can be used to describe behaviour with adjectives, which are actions:

> He and Nick **are being** helpful.

This means the two are acting in a helpful way.